# ¿Cómo puedo hacer Zoom a una ImageView como Instagram?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, zoom, instagram

¿Alguien sabe como hacer zoom en una ImageView y salga fuera de los limites este?

Yo uso la librería PhotoView con Java y funciona bien, pero me gustaría hacer zoom a un ImageView fuera de los limites dados en el XML y que no afectase a los demás objetos, como sucede en la app de Intagram.

Un saludo a todos y gracias.

Comment: Solo tienes q animar tu mismo, moverla y hacerla grande con los touch de los dedos. Existe la clase gesturedetector  scalegesturedetector para el zoom algo asi se llaman, te da un factor de escala y con eso escalas tu imageview. Ya ta echo lo del factor si tener que hacerlo manual como antes se hacia.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he buscado la clase que me has aconsejado, pero no consigo llevar a cabo lo que busco. Estoy intentando implementar esto [Arrastre y ajuste de tamaño](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale#basic-scaling-example)  Pero no consigo ajustar la View como deseo.

Comment: Agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask], con PhotoView se puede realizar, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, estuve intentando aplicarlo con PhotoView pero afectaba a los objetos de alrededor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente encontré [Zoomy](https://github.com/imablanco/Zoomy) y funciona perfectamente.

Solo hay que implementar en el Gradle (Module):

```
implementation 'com.ablanco.zoomy:zoomy:1.1.0'
```

Y esto en la actividad o fragmento donde se aloja tu ImageView

```
Zoomy.Builder builder = new Zoomy.Builder(getActivity()).target(imageView);
builder.register();
```

Espero que os sirva, un saludo y gracias. ✌

Comment: Deberías especificar que problema tuviste con PhotoView, puede realizar lo mismo sin problema.

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar, no tuve ningún problema con PhotoView, solo buscaba hacer zoom a un ImageView fuera de los limites dados en el XML y que no afectase a los demás objetos

Comment: No sabia de esta me puede servir, aunque yo me la hice manual mi zoom tipo whatsapp.